# Attribute Driven Design

Tags: design, architecture, methodology

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attribute-driven_design):

> Attribute-driven design (also called ADD or Attribute-driven design
> method) is a methodology to create software architectures that takes
> into account the quality attributes of the software.

Why is Attribute driven design, as described in books such as "Designing Software Architectures: A Practical Approach" and "Software Architecture in Practice", the latter canonically blessed by the IEEE SWEBOK(v3, current v4 draft) and used in many graduate courses in software architecture around the world, so unknown compared to alternatives such as domain driven design, despite being developed initially around the same time?

Is there any historical reason for this? Is it because DDD lends itself better to the microservices philosophy of a service-per-business-function?

Comment: ADD, as described by Wikipedia, seems to be so general it will be hard to find a design process which you cannot just put that label on. Software design won't get better by inventing new buzzwords for it.

Comment: ... and I also took the time to have a look into [ADD 2.0](https://resources.sei.cmu.edu/asset_files/TechnicalReport/2006_005_001_14795.pdf). Sorry, but this looks a lot like  hot air to to me - 55 pages to explain the standard analytical approach of stepwise refinement.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is darwinistic: methods that are useful to solve real problems gain traction, get improved and survive. Methods that do not sufficiently address real problems remain on the bookshelf and die.

The theoretical background to this [natural selection process](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_selection) in the method space can be found in Darwin’s [On the origin of species](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/On_the_Origin_of_Species), adapted to methods which have no genome but rather sets of practices and other constituents.

Moreover all design practices are somewhat attribute oriented, since in the end they intend to design [quality software](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_9126) that fulfill requirements, work accurately, are maintainable, performant and usable. It’s just that some provide more practical and effective ways to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is marketing: Methods that are sold aggressively by consultants to large companies gain traction and snowball. Once a couple of big names have adopted them they become easier to sell and seen as a "must know" in the industry.

Of course the content does matter to an extent. But its not so much about effectiveness as having an easy to understand concept and identifying a ubiquitous problem.

In the case of DDD the problem is:

"I ask my developers to do what I think should be a simple thing and they say its hard because 'the system' is designed in a way which makes my change hard"

The solution is:

"Make developers design the system in the way that the business talks about the system. Then you wont have this disconnect!"

And there are some good ideas in there, use the same language, recognise that different parts of the business think about things differently even though they might use the same names etc etc.

Everyone recognises the problem, this smart suited consultant says he has the solution and can train your team! The developers have looked it over and seen some stuff they agree with. Its an easy sell, plus you read (the consultant told you) that Microsoft have used it in one of their "big projects"! its a win win!

One of your devs says maybe we should do ADD instead, you googled it and

"The ADD method is an approach to defining a software architecture in which the
design process is based on the software’s quality attribute requirements. ADD follows a recursive design process that d....." Zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

Its confusing and no one is selling you a training course in it, Does it solve the problem the consultant says you have? Who else is using it? How much would it cost to adopt? Why isn't your developer researching these answers and showing you them in a powerpoint with an expensive suit on? Besides you don't pay him as much as the consultant charges, so he must be less clever.

OK got a bit ranty there but you get the idea. Lots of design and work patterns get tried out, but the ones with household names are the ones that are easy to sell. Not the ones that work.

Comment: Even Eric Evans himself would probably agree that DDD is mostly about marketing. I remember him protesting when someone said that Evans invented DDD. Evans responded something like "Actually, DDD is just good Object-Oriented Design. I just wrote it down and gave it names". (Which, actually, is what a good part of DDD itself is about: find good names.)